# How to execute a script only if it is present, in bash?

Tags: bash

I wonder if there is a simpler way to execute a script in bash only if this script exists. What I want is equivalent to:

```
if [ -x $name ]
then
  $name
fi
```

or

```
[ -x $name ] && $name
```

What I am looking for is something like

```
exec_if_exist $name
```

which eliminates repetition of the script name.

Is there a way to simplify this in bash?
I do not want a function or "speculative" execution, which would give the command not found error.

Best

Comment: so want like `rm` command which delete file if exist like `rm -f script.sh` right? In your case you want execute it.

Comment: I figured something simpler: test -x $name && $_

Answer (score 9):

You can simplify it somewhat with the `type` command. With your tests, it requires a full or relative path to the file. With `type` it will search the PATH.

```
type $name && $name
```

it is also nice because it puts success on STDOUT and failure on STDERR, giving you complete control over the output

```
# mute success
type >/dev/null
# mute fail
type 2>/dev/null
# mute both
type &>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not

```
exec_if_exist() {
    test -x $1 && $1
}
```

And, the path may need to be considered when invoking $1.

Comment: I do not want a function as I need to define it somewhere and handle later (e.g. source). thx

Comment: Hi again, Thank you I figured out a little bit simpler form: test -x $name && $_ It works for me!

Answer (score 2):

`type` did not seem to always work on OS X. What worked was

```
which -s command && command
```