# Redirect an executable's stdout/stderr but not invocation-time errors from the shell

Tags: bash, scripting, io-redirection

I have a simple bash script that launches an executable in the background and redirects stdout + stderr to a log file:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
myexec >& logfile &
```

It works. However, output from `myexec` isn't the only thing that gets redirected: any messages that `bash` emits while attempting to invoke `myexec` are also going to `logfile`. To wit, if `bash` doesn't find `myexec`, I don't get to see the `myexec: No such file or directory` error because it went straight to `logfile` instead of to the terminal. This behavior annoys me because I end up not knowing whether the script succeeded in starting up `myexec`.

It occurs to me that the script could just test for the existence of `myexec` before trying to invoke it, but I'm wondering whether there isn't a way to do the redirection itself in such a way that only `myexec`'s output, and not the shell's, gets redirected.

Comment: No, there isn't really, though perhaps you could try some of the answers in this near-duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926647/how-to-execute-a-script-only-if-it-is-present-in-bash

Comment: That `No such file or directory` comes back from the execve() syscall, which takes place after the `fork()` and all the file descriptor redirection already happened. I don't see an obvious way to implement a shell that *doesn't* have this behavior, at least without creating a hard dependency on an operating system having `O_CLOEXEC` to maintain a separate mechanism for passing errors back over a FIFO that gets automatically closed on a successful exec.

Comment: Thank you both. @charles-duffy, your explanation makes it clear why it behaves this way. @tripleee, from your link I see that there exist hacks that are not overly ugly. I've settled on the form `myexec > logfile 2>&1 && echo "ok" >&2 || echo "nope." >&2`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to separate the outputs in the way the OP describes. As Charles Duffy explains in his comment, the system call that opens (or fails to open) the executable `myexec` takes place after Bash has forked a new process, at which point all of the I/O redirection has already been set up. There is, however, a workaround that suffices for the purpose stated in the OP, namely, "knowing whether the script succeeded in starting up myexec":

```
myexec > logfile 2>&1 && echo "ok" >&2 || echo "nope." >&2
```

Comment: The only problem here is that it treats any nonzero exit status from `myexec` the same way as an inability to fork. As you say, though, this limit is pretty much unavoidable with UNIX being designed as it is -- part of why systemd has `Type=forking` (so a failure before the process forks is treated as the process not having started successfully, whereas the forked-off process eventually exiting with a nonzero status is treated as a successful start and then a later failure) and `Type=notify` (where the process is responsible for writing updates on its current status over a socket).